# not sure where did i install such package

Tags: python

After I do some `python setup.py develop` . I am trying to figure out which pyabinitio is installed in my Mac. (I use conda to manage python and other packages). What returned is from ipython:

```
In [1]: import pyabinitio

In [2]: pyabinitio.__path__
Out[2]: ['pyabinitio']

In [3]: pyabinitio.__file__
Out[3]: 'pyabinitio/__init__.py'

In [4]: pyabinitio.__file__
```

It does not tell where the pyabinitio is installed... Did I miss anything? Thank you.

Comment: Exit the console and get out of the directory where you are (`cd ..` or something). Then you can open python again and check.

Comment: This works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `pkg_resources`:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('pyabinitio')
```

This will display the distribution name, version and location (path).

See [Getting or Creating Distributions](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#getting-or-creating-distributions) in SetupTools documentation.